# Spring r2dbc composite support

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

It seems Spring r2dbc does not support Composite Primary Key / Embedded Classes.

What other options or work around can be followed in this case?

If i have a table which has Composite Key, then how can I get Flux of objects using partial key, may be the first column?

For e.g

```
repository.findAllById(String id);

Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [annotated queries](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/reference/html/#r2dbc.repositories.queries) or you may use the [`R2dbcEntityTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/r2dbc/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/r2dbc/core/R2dbcEntityTemplate.html#insert-T-)